# Jquery UI Sortable - Draggable - lose sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery ui sortable list. I set up a "trash can" to get rid of items I didn't want on a list. Once I had the 'draggable' set up on my list items, they no longer sort.

trash can

```
$("#trash").droppable({
      drop: function(ev, li)
      {
        var $element = li.draggable;
        $element.remove();
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'deltask.php',                          
        data: 'id='+$element.attr('id'),            
        dataType: 'html',                   
        success: function(data)          
        {
        }
    });

      }
});
```

Making the list sortable

```
    // set our listdiv ul as sortable 
    $("#listdiv ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function(){
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=update'; 
        $.post("updatelist.php", order, function(){
        });                                                              
    }                                 
    }); // listdiv ul end
```

and making all list items in that ul draggable so I can drag and trash:

```
    $("#listdiv li").draggable({
        opacity : 0.7,
        revert  : 'invalid',
                helper  : 'clone',
                zIndex  : 100,
                cursor  : 'move'
        });
```

Sorting works as long as I don't include the section just above that makes the `<li>`'s draggable. Adding that let's me drag and trash em but the list items are no longer sortable.

What's my bad, please?

Thanks,
Steve

***NOTE: I don't know the protocol for answering ones own question so I'm just editing my original question! Someone slap me if I'm wrong to do this pls.***

Workaround to the problem stated above:

After sleeping on it I thought "Why bother with making my sortable list `<li>`'s draggable and make my trash can a droppable?"

I just make my trash can a sortable and use `connectwith` on my list div and trash div and set up a receive event handler and that should work? Let's see...

```
$("#trash").sortable({

      connectWith: '#listdiv',
      receive: function(event, ui)
      {
     var $element = ui.item;
//        alert ( $element.attr('id') ) ;

        // remove this from original list
        $element.remove();

    //remove this item from trash list
    $("#trash li").remove(),

        // remove from database
    $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'deltask.php',                          
            data: 'id='+$element.attr('id'),            
            dataType: 'html',                   
            success: function(data)          
            {
            //  alert(data);
            }
    });

      } // end receive
}); // end trash



// set our listdiv ul as sortable 
$("#listdiv ul").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: '#trash',
    update: function()
        {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=update'; 
            $.post("updatelist.php", order, function(){
            });      
        }   
}); // end  listdiv ul sortable
```

My original list sorts fine and I can drag a list item to the trash "list" and just remove() it when it arrives from the original list, the trash list, and from my database.

Perhaps not too elegant but hey, it works.